# What is the maximum level in euro truck simulator 2?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I wonder what the maximum level for your profile on euro truck simulator 2 is. I've found parts which will be unlocked at level 30, which would mean, that you can not max out every skill.

Does anybody know the exact levelcap for this game?

Comment: I am not sure, but so far I have made it to level 26 - which is about 80000 experience. Assuming that the cap is level 30 then this means you can fully fill all but one set of skills. I will update once I get to level 30ish and see if I keep getting levels.

Comment: That's right. The cap needs to be 36 to max out every skill (6 skills with 6 points each). I'm just level 12, so it will take some time to get to that point ;)

Comment: yes it gets quite time consuming per level once you've got quite high

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ETS 2 has a file contains info about levels. Here is fragment of that file:

```
#   Level names "level_limit|level name" 
# 
level_names[]: "0|@@lvl_name0@@|0xFFe0e0e0" 
level_names[]: "5|@@lvl_name1@@|0xFF45c294" 
level_names[]: "10|@@lvl_name2@@|0xFF75baea" 
level_names[]: "15|@@lvl_name3@@|0xFF3a88f4" 
level_names[]: "20|@@lvl_name4@@|0xFF5847f0" 
level_names[]: "25|@@lvl_name5@@|0xFFda9356" 
level_names[]: "30|@@lvl_name6@@|0xFFf58493" 
level_names[]: "40|@@lvl_name7@@|0xFFc99ef2" 
level_names[]: "50|@@lvl_name8@@|0xFFc2f9ff" 

# 
#   experience points to the next level 
# 
level_xp[0]: 200 
level_xp[1]: 500 
level_xp[2]: 700 
level_xp[3]: 900 
level_xp[4]: 1000 
level_xp[5]: 1100
```

It is easy to conclude that after level 50 your name of rank will stay the same. And the maximum level, according this long file, is **150** (but I can't say for sure if any new patch changed that, it's confirmed after patch 1.2.5).

Comment: What file is that? to make sure that the content of this answer has not changed.

Answer (score -2):

The maximum level is 75 in Euro Truck Simulator 2.

Comment: Do you have a source?